# Is there a way to detect if running code is being executed inside a context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

As the title states, is there a way to do something like this:

```
def call_back():
    if called inside context:
        print("running in context")
    else:
        print("called outside context")
```

And this would result in:

```
with CTM() as context:
    call_back()
call_back()

>>> "running in context"
>>> "called outside context"
```

Comment: Not without using the `inspect` module, I'd think. There's nothing really special about the block of code in a `with` statement, aside from the guarantee that `context.__enter__` will be called prior to executing it and `context.__exit__` will be called after.

Comment: It depends. Do you control the code for the context manager? Because if you do, you could update some global or object-specific state to indicate whether you are inside the context manager or not. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've decided to go with updating some sort of flag from the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of the context manager.

Answer (score 1):

As @chepner wrote in the comments of the question

> Not [possible] without using the `inspect` module, I'd think. There's nothing really special about the block of code in a with statement, aside from the guarantee that `context.__enter__` will be called prior to executing it and `context.__exit__` will be called after.

Then @larsks suggested that if you have control over the context manager...

> ... you could update some global or object-specific state to indicate whether you are inside the context manager or not.

This seems to be the solution finally adopted by @new-dev-123.

Here you have that solution:

```
class CTM:
    def __init__(self):
        self._is_in_context = False   
    def __enter__(self):
        self._is_in_context = True
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._is_in_context = False
    def call_back(self):
        if self._is_in_context:
            print("running in context")
        else:
            print("called outside context")
```

```
>>> with CTM() as context:
...     context.call_back()
running in context
>>> context.call_back()
called outside context
```

If you want the same behaviour for multiple methods, or to keep responsibilities separated, you can use a decorator.

```
def reveal_context(func):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._is_in_context:
            print("running in context")
        else:
            print("called outside context") 
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner
    
class CTM:
    def __init__(self):
        self._is_in_context = False
    def __enter__(self):
        self._is_in_context = True
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._is_in_context = False
    @reveal_context
    def call_back(self):
        pass
```