# Decorator to raise exception if not in context

Tags: python, decorator

I did not find a direct answer to this question and I find it quite usefull.
For example, I am developing a database interface, therefore, I am creating a class with methods that should only run when inside the class context, otherwise raise an exception:

```py
with DBInterfaceContext() as session:
    session.do_something1()
    session.do_something2()
```

This class implements the `do_something` methods, that should only be used when the connection to the database/other is done trhough the `__enter__` method.

Here a basic template of what to achieve:

```py
from contextlib import AbstractContextManager
from functools import wraps

class DBInterfaceContext(AbstractContextManager):
    """This is the DB interface example to build"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        ....

    def __enter__(self):
        ...
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def require_session(meth):  # Decorator method
        ...
        @wraps(meth)
        def wrapped_method(self, *args, **kwds):
            if not self.in_session():
                raise RuntimeError(f"Method {meth} called out of session")
            return meth(self, *args, **kwds)
        return wrapped_method

    @DBInterfaceContext.require_session
    def do_something1(self, *args, **kwds):
        ...

    @DBInterfaceContext.require_session
    def do_something2(self, *args, **kwds):
        ...
```

Feel free to modify the example as much as you like for the example and share your experience.
Great thanks!

Comment: Store a boolean flag on the class instance that gets set on \_\_enter\_\_ and cleared on \_\_exit\_\_. I still say this is *probably* going to cause more problems than it solves so I'm not writing it as an answer, but you do you.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829275/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-running-code-is-being-executed-inside-a-context-mana and the comments on it

Comment: That is possible, and not far from what I wrote, but it introduces code that might be reduced using an available library. I search inside contextlib but did not find anything. Maybe the community know of a package that already implements `require_session`.